# Loading remote data, caching, and continuing in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Basic use case. I have a global variable where I store remotely pulled data. If there is no data then I want to load it initially, wait for it load, and then continue processing. I don't really want to use a synchronous process if I don't have to.

Consider something like this where _companies is a global variable...

```
    if (_companies === undefined || _companies.length == 0) {
       loadExternalData();
    }
    // do something with the data in _companies
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I understand that I can call async = false but that seems like a cludge. I could also put all the code in the  block in a function, make an if..else and then call the function from loadExternalData() as well as in my else statement but again that seems like a cludge. It seems like I should be able to wrap that entire thing in a callback but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Side note: Always use `typeof variable === 'undefined'`.  Technically you can override `undefined` ... such as `var undefined = 'now I am a string!';`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking but setTimeout() / setInterval() can help with scheduling/checking during app runtime. I don't understand why you want to do it async = false though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below, including the comments. The code has the same structure as the functions in your question. If anything is unclear, add a comment.

```
var companies; //Cache
function loadExternalData(callback){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ //Set readystatechange event
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){ //Request finished: 200 OK
            callback(xhr.responseText); //Call callback func with data
        }
    }
    xhr.open("get", "http://example.com", true); //True = async
    xhr.send(null);
}

function parseData(data){
    if(data) {//If data is defined, set companies
        _companies = data;
    }
    if (typeof _companies == "undefined" || _companies.length == 0) {
       loadExternalData(parseData); //Pass callback function
       return; //No data, return function
    }
    //When the function reaches this point, _companies exist.
    //Normal function behavior
}
```

See also: **[MDN: Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)**

Comment: I had actually gotten to a similar point based on the advice of a coworker. I'm going to take a look at this code compared to what I mucked together.

Comment: What if there is a second call to the original operation while the first asynchronous call is already in flight? An unnecessary second call will be triggered (because `_companies` has still not been assigned to yet).

Comment: @DanielEarwicker If you want to take care of that case, a third variable/flag has to be used, which keeps track of the function's state. This flag should be checked upon calling the function. When the request fails, the flag should be toggled, to enable a re-try. When the request succeeds, the flag should not be touched, unless the cache should be refreshed.

Comment: I'm also wondering about the situation where each call coming in (e.g. to your `parseData`) provides its own callback so it can be notified when the data is available. If three such calls are made, then when the (single) call to the backend completes, all three callbacks must be called to notify them. So in that situation you'd need a list of all waiting callbacks.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker `parseData` (in this situation) caches one request. Note that the `callback` in `loadExternalData` is `parseData`. So, this function will always deal with one type of data. You're correct about qeueing callback requests if `parseData` contains function logic which looks like `_companies.count++` (an expression which always modifies a value). If `parseData`'s function logic only populates an input field using `_companies`, then it's not needed to remember the qeue.

Comment: True, these are really different questions. It would be interesting to write a general-purpose async cache facility that could wrap around any situation... but it would belong more in a blog post than under this question! :)