# Tricky design for UserControl performance

Tags: asp.net, web-services, user-controls

I need to deliver a User Control to a client. It has a text field such that when you type characters into it, it does an Ajax auto-complete which looks up the matching items at the server.

The data for the items comes from some XML retrived from a web service i.e. very slow. How can I possibly avoid having users wait for this data to load?

The XML data is finite; it can *all* be cahced but the first request, at least, will be slow. The trouble is that because I'm only delivering a UserControl, I don't have access to the Application or Session Start events so I don't see how I can pre-load the data.

Comment: Since you are only delivering a User Control, there is no way you can Cache the Webservice Result for the first time. The only option is to deal with it or for the Client to Cache the WebService Result in the Application_Start event, and for your UserControl to use it.

Comment: How many items (max) can there be?  10? 100? 10000? 1 trillion?  I mean every possible item, not just the ones shown at any given time.

Comment: So once I have the data cached, how would I refresh it? I was thinking of checking the timestamp of the cached data and if its out of date, start a fire and forget thread to refresh it but having the current web request just use the stale data for the time being. I think I'd need to set a flag in Application state which indicates that a refresh is under way as well because otherwise there could be many attempt to refresh the data at the same time.

Comment: @Chris I think there can be a few hundred. Its countries and cities.

Comment: Turns out this is not really an issue at all... I just need to make sure that some XML in a file is deployed with the user control. Then there'll always be at least some data available on disk. This data can be loaded into the ASP cache on PageLoad so some lucky user will have an extra second of delay when this is first done - that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can download them in javascript and cache them in a JS variable.

The answer to this question gives good example code on how to do an async http request from JavaScript to pull data directly into the browser: [Loading remote data, caching, and continuing in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826746/loading-remote-data-caching-and-continuing-in-javascript), bypassing the server, session state, application vars, etc.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Something I didn't mention though is that even though the data is quite limited, its actually spread across multiple web services. I think its the multiple requests that are the bottle neck.

Comment: It will certainly make it more complicated, but client-side AJAX requests can (in many modern browsers) be sent to multiple servers at once, so you get some parallelism wins there.

Comment: I think the simplest thing to do is to demand that the client lets us insert some code into their Global.ascx's App Start event handler. Doing that is not unusual for a third party control. Then the issue just becomes one of managing cached data.